# Add new symbol to activerecord array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to sort my activerecord result using a new calculated field but am unsure how to add a new field to the activerecord array. My code

```
def index 

@customers = Customer.first(2)

end
```

Returns an array from the ActiveRecord result

```
    [#<Customer id: 1, customer_name: "BOB", 
street: "1 Long Street", suburb: "BELMONT", state: "QLD", 
postcode: "4153", price_list_id: "AAA111">,
#<Customer id: 2, customer_name: "TONY", 
street: "1 Short Street", suburb: "BELMONT", state: "QLD", 
postcode: "4153", price_list_id: "BBB222">]
```

I want to add a new symbol being `:revenue`. This symbol will be calculated fields. I have been Googling for a few days now and just can't seem to find the answer.

I just want my new array to be:

```
[#<Customer id: 1, customer_name: "BOB", 
street: "1 Long Street", suburb: "BELMONT", state: "QLD", 
postcode: "4153", price_list_id: "AAA111", revenue: "">,
#<Customer id: 2, customer_name: "TONY", 
street: "1 Short Street", suburb: "BELMONT", state: "QLD", 
postcode: "4153", price_list_id: "BBB222", revenue: "">]
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I will then populate the revenue field using a helper method in ApplicationHelper as follows:

```
def sum_yearly_revenue(id, year)
  sum_yearly_revenue = Sale.sum(:revenue, :conditions => ['id = ? AND financial_year = ?', id, year])
end
```

Where `id` is the Customer id field and `year` would be "2014".

Comment: Are you having `revenue` in `customers` table?

Comment: Yes I do but each row represents monthly data. My intention is to calculate the customers yearly revenue so that I can sort the ActiveRecord array in descending order for my index view.

Comment: so my follow up question after I solve this would then be how to populate the :revenue symbol using a method that I have stored in my ApplicationHelper called yearly_revenue. If I am going down the wrong path altogether please feel free to pull me up

Comment: Can you post your `yearly_revenue` code?

Comment: Ok, I have appended this to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [sort_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by). Something like:

```
customers.sort_by { |c| ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a new field to the active record array.

It looks like you are using a **service object** **Sale** in order to calculate the yearly revenue.

That is independent of your customer model. Don't mix the two responsabilities. So don't create a calculated field for that.

Architecturally the most correct design would be to retrieve the customers you want to sort in your controller.
Next sort them with a service object.

Something like:

class SortByYearlyRevenue
  attr_reader :coll
  def initialize(collection)
    @coll = collection.to_a
  end
  def execute(year)
    coll.map{|x| [x, Sale.sum(:revenue, :conditions => ['id = ? AND financial_year = ?', x.id, year])]}.sort_by{|x| x[1]}
  end
end

```
def index
  customers = User.first(2)
  @customers = SortByYearlyRevenue.new(customers).execute(params[:year])
  puts @customers
end
```

Then you should create a service object in app/services/sort_by_yearly_revenue.rb

```
class SortByYearlyRevenue
  attr_reader :coll
  def initialize(collection)
    @coll = collection.to_a
  end
  def execute(year)
    coll.map{|x| [x, Sale.sum(:revenue, :conditions => ['id = ? AND financial_year = ?', x.id, year])]}.sort_by{|x| x[1]}
  end
end
```

Then you won't need the 'sum_yearly_revenue' helper method.

In your view you will have an array with two values for each row. The first value will be the activerecord object the second one will be the calculated field.

Comment: Wow thank you Boti. There is a whole lot in that I haven't learnt yet so I'll go away, give it a crack and see how it goes. Thank you for your suggestion. If it all works I'll come back and  tick it off.

Comment: Should it be SortByYearlyRevenue.initialize(customers).execute?

Comment: @JayKilleen I corrected the typos in my code. You can check it now.